# How much can transposing a song by a half step or a whole step help a vocalist?

Tags: voice, transposition

It is not uncommon for a singer to ask for a piece to be transposed up or down a half step or a whole step. This minute change might be a big change for instrumentalist, like horn players, who have to play the song in a completely different key that the original song. It would make more sense in most cases to transpose up or down a 4th or a 5th to a closely related key that would be well in the range for a vocalist, but this is rarely ever the case.

How much can transposing a song by a small interval (whole step or half step) help a vocalist and does it outweigh the difficulty for the other instruments?

Comment: Not much, if I'm trying to sing anything by Paul McCartney.  I need at least a fourth.  :) Seriously, though, there are songs I have trouble with that I can do a lot better if I drop it a whole step. I'm pretty much a baritone. If you want a bit of an education on this subject, see if you can find "Am I Too Loud?", a delightful recording of lectures by the great English accompanist Gerald Moore. He manages to be both very educational and funny at the same time.

Comment: In addition to the answers that mention range considerations, there is also vocal transitions that can play a part. Even if a song is well within a singers range a vocal transition (say from chest voice to head voice) may occur at a difficult point in the melody, during a long legato phrase for example. The singer may choose to play the song higher or lower so the entire phrase can be sung without having to transition from one register to another. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_register

Comment: Can't see how transposing a 4th up or down, *to a related key* is a great deal of help. In fact, it could take some instruments out of their range, and they consequently would have to play an octave out, then.

Comment: A well-known example in classical music is Elisabeth Schwarzkopf's recording of Strauss' *Four Last Songs* with George Szell, in which *Früling* is transposed down a half step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's unreasonable for a singer to accommodate the band with regard to a key change interval of a whole or half-step, or not. If your singer cannot do this, then maybe you need to find a better singer. But please read on.

The short answer is that it depends on the particular song paired with a particular singer, and there is no hard-and-fast rule about it. If a particular song contained a lot of notes that are all the way at the bottom or all the way at the top of a singer's range, then I can understand why a singer would want to change the key accordingly.

Most singers have a range of less than two octaves, depending on what they were born with and what techniques they have developed. The different voice types; bass, baritone, tenor, alto, mezzo and soprano, each have a different range of pitches in their natural range. A small number of women have a very wide range, from high tenor to soprano, but most do not. Some men learn to shift effortlessly from their natural range up to falsetto, but few can do this and make it sound musically useful.

The term to describe the range of notes that must be sung in a song is *[tessitura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessitura)*. It describes not only an "inventory" of all the pitches, but whether or not the melody lines are weighted towards the lower or higher range. This is different for every song, and there is no precise formula for measuring it.

To avoid disagreement, it's reasonable to ask your singer to work out what songs he or she would like to sing with your band in advance, and to agree before the jam session about the keys. If your band and the singer cannot agree on a key transposition on a certain song, then it just won't work, and you should ask the singer to suggest different songs that might work, and sort it out beforehand. Make it the singer's responsibility to provide his or her own written-out charts in the key that you agree on, if the members of your band cannot transpose a chart on sight for a difficult song.

And never ask a guitar band in standard tuning to play a song in the key of E-flat.

(The latest generation of iPad fake book chart software, such as [iRealPro](http://irealpro.com), automates the real-time transposition of charts like magic, but this product only provides for transposing the chord progression, since it does not support displaying the instrumental melody lines at all.)

If you get the idea that you are working with a singer with a weak voice and a very limited vocal range, who always asks for unreasonable transpositions, then perhaps you should look for a better singer with better technique. But if the singer is the star of the show and gets the gigs, then you may have to accommodate them.

In 35 years of singing, I have *never* encountered a song that I could sing if it were shifted a 4th or a 5th higher or lower in pitch than what I asked for. That would be too much for most singers, unless you are talking about a song with a very narrow tessitura, maybe a melody where every single note falls within the range of a fifth. There are very few songs like that.

Comment: I was asking how much can a half step or whole step transposition helps a vocalist not why do singer need to sing in different keys. To me and other instrumentalist, it seems like transposing up or down a half step won't really make a difference on the range of a piece, but I could be wrong. So does a half step have a big impact on vocals?

Comment: OK, maybe I went a bit overboard in my answer! The short answer is that for some songs, a whole step might make little difference, but for other songs, it might make a big difference. It just depends on the melody. I'll modify my answer and tone down my response a bit. Give me a minute to think on it.

Comment: E-flat? Don't get me started on _D_. Some songs you can play in E-flat though by going E drop D, but that usually requires pen and paper, at least for me.

Answer (score 10):

Speaking as (primarily) a vocalist: A half step can be the difference between the singer being able to hit the high or low note at acceptable volume/clarity -- or at all! -- and not being able to do so. And that can vary from day to day, which is why it's a good idea to know and avoid the limits of their range (and to sanity-check during the band's warm-up).

I'm not a great singer, just adequate. There's a song I do which just about covers my range. If I start in the right key I can sing it. A trifle higher or lower and I can't. It really is that simple. Not a problem for me since I'm doing it acapulco; not a problem for folks who either are comfortable with my key or who can capo or transpose into it; definitely a problem if someone has an instrument which has trouble with that key and can't figure out a way to cheat around it.

Figure this out in rehearsal. The answer may be that that singer, and that instrument, just aren't going to be able to do this song together without a lot of re-arranging. And that's OK; if you can't find an answer you like, drop it and move on... or find a set of performers that work better together. Sometimes it just doesn't click and that's nobody's fault.

(My girlfriend and I will probably never be able to sing as a duo. We're both in the baritone range, but our ranges and the breaks in our voices are offset just enough that we strain to sing unison and can rarely sing harmony... and from day to day, it's never clear which of us is going to be singing above or below the other. Some day maybe we'll figure out a way to make it work, but I'm not counting on it. There are a few songs with a limited range that we can get away with, but...)

Comment: I accompanied a singer singing "O Holy Night" at a Christmas service.  At rehearsal it was clear that the high note was just out of his range.  I took it down only one-half step and it made all the difference in the world!

Comment: That should be 'a capella', not 'acapulco'!

Comment: Deliberate misuse, @No'amNewman. Traditional minor joke. Very minor.

Comment: @keshlam Start growling. You never know... she might be the next Angela Gossow ;) (absolutely NO offense intended)

Comment: Since you're doing the song 'acapulco', why would a guitarist need a capo at all?

Comment: @Tim: In song circles, jams, instabands and other less-formal/more-social performance, you can wind up with accompanists you didn't rehearse with  -- or wind up being one yourself. The fact that I start a capella and solo doesn't always mean I'll end the song that way. If I want specific folks to be able to join in, it helps to pick a key that doesn't tie their instrument (or voice) in knots.

Comment: ... but you're right, that could be better phrased to reflect the two distinct cases.

Comment: Starting acapella doesn't necessarily mean you've put yourself in a suitable key - unless you have absolute pitch - but it probably puts your voice in the right ball park. Many's the time I've accompanied voices and had to move the start key a fair bit.

Answer (score 9):

Naturally I agree with the posters who have mentioned vocal range.  In addition to range, however, there are two other considerations: breaks and color.

A break is where a vocalist's voice cuts over from head voice to chest voice.  Sometimes a vocalist isn't all that stable where the break is.  If (s)he is singing a song that hovers around C, and his or her vocal break is around C, it's going to be a nightmare.  Moving the melody up or down even a little bit can be very helpful.

Color is also important.  Some vocalists have sweet spots in their range that make certain vowels shine.  Moving out of that range even a little bit can change the color of their sound.

Naturally, a well-trained vocalist has worked very hard to make their vocal break and changes of color unnoticeable to the extent possible.  A vocal coach teaches us how to make things even and smooth.  Nonetheless, if you're singing something very challenging or very expressive, every little bit helps.

If you are interested in hearing this action, try listening to [Give You What You Like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwrng3YkNU) by Avril Lavigne. This piece has a challenging range for Avril, and she uses all three of her voices: a breathy falsetto, a plaintive head voice, and a chest voice that could be described as sultry. She switches deftly among them throughout, but the noteworthy break occurs on the word "maybe" in the line "Is this love? Maybe some day" (the line occurs several times in every chorus). You can clearly hear here that she is utilizing the break between her head voice and falsetto to lend the line a sadness and longing that is consistent with the theme of the song.

Comment: A well-trained vocalist should be able to sing uniformly over a decent range of pitches, but there's no reason a well-trained vocalist shouldn't *also* be able to exploit sweet spots in their range if they coincide with musically sensible spots in the melody.

Answer (score 6):

It mainly depends on the RANGE of the song in question.In a song which has notes too high to sing comfortably, it needs to be lowered. Let's take it down a tone. This could make the highest notes easier to sing, and would make the lowest notes only a little lower - no big deal. But - if that song was moved down by a 4th, then the lowest notes would also be a 4th down. At this point, the singer may be having difficulty reaching the lower notes of the song. Top notes = very comfortable. For a singer with a fair range, most pop type songs will stand being moved up, or down, by a 5th.Given a song with a range of say, a 10th, and a limited range singer, we're talking about a small window of key change.

On occasions, working in bands, various singers have asked for key changes to songs. After going through several, and asking the singer to stand up to sing, he/she has said 'yes, that's a good key'. I have never had the heart to mention that they were actually back in the original that didn't work before...

So, it's down to the tessitura of the song, and the range of the vocalist.There was a recent post about a similar issue on this site.

I agree that moving a song a semitone up or down will hardly make a difference to a vocalist, but will mean a lot of re-planning for some instrumentalists.I've usually found the change of key is needed when there is 4/5 part harmony, to get each voice in a comfy range.

Comment: "I have never had the heart to mention that they were actually back in the original that didn't work before..."  But afterward they were a bit more warmed up than before, no? :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like everyone else said, it depends. If the song stays at the top, or near the top of your range, bringing it down makes it WAY easier. For example, I am pretty comfortable hitting an F#4, but I dread having to sing a G4. I can somewhat hit a G#, and I have hit an A once or twice. Also, like some have said, if the instrumentalists and the singer are constantly clashing about key changes, maybe there isn't the chemistry you need. Every band I have been in has had instruments like piano, drums and guitar. No horns or violins. So in the past, transposing has not been too big of a deal.
But just being considerate of the other band members is also really important. I've played piano songs transposed without any notice or practice in the new key because of one other band member. I've also sang a song in a key that's half a step higher than I'd like just because it's not plausible for our guitar player to play in Db. They'll understand if you sound bad for the first little while. Although I can see that it is a little bit different for horn players.

Answer (score 2):

Most pop songs by male artist are sung by lighter/high baritones. Those high baritones who have really good technique and a big range can pull off songs like "maneater" (Hall and oates) in B minor, "still got the blues" (Gary moore) in d-minor and true tenors with decent technique could do them more easy and probably the better ones can do a song like "run to you" (bryan adams) in F#-minor and sound great.

For deeper baritones with more bottom heavy voices, that half step from B-minor to Bb-minor for a song like maneater makes a lot of difference. Daryl Hall should actually transpose his sings a half key today.. He is struggling to hit those notes as in his youth..

Even my own bands singer who is a high-pitched baritone struggles to sing maneater in its original key. He is slightly flat in the verses and strain a little.. We are in the process of trying e-flat tuning on the guitar and bass as songs like "hip to be square" (huey lewis..), "Life is highway" (cochran) in their original key utilize the low E on bass and guitar and those songs are just one half key away for our singer to sing them without straining a little which is not good if you are singing more than 2 hours straight..

Answer (score 1):

It makes a huge difference to a vocalist, in my experience.

The transpositions for instruments will depend on what sort of music you're playing and how well can the musicians transpose on the go. Wind players are usually much more used to transposing everything.
I think it's safe to say that everyone will like to have a pre-transposed score instead of having to do that on the go though. So it's best to get someone to do the transpositions and then supply the musicians with scores ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Vocalist should have 17 notes in the range of their chest voice 13 are needed to make a clean octave, that leaves 4 half steps.  You do need to accommodate them.  However you also should be able to move up to an additional whole step beyond what they're asking to stay in sane scales for everyone else (i.e. C,F,Bb,Eb,Ab,G).

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular songs I love to explore this issue about comfort with the key is "Happy Birthday."

It's funny when somebody takes up singing that they then set out to find what is their preferred key for "Happy Birthday."  Sometimes they find a good key, yet it's still not quite right.  In particular, the challenging part is on the 3rd Happy Birthday which goes up an octave.  So by going to a new key a half step or whole step close by, they can sing the whole song comfortably.

As a kind of comical thing with other musicians, we sometimes wonder when we're at a restaurant eating and not gigging what key "Happy Birthday" will be sung in.  We then also wonder if it'll end up in the same key; many times it does not.  Pay attention next time and observe how many times the whole song falls apart at the 3rd Happy Birthday pitchwise.  (It also is complicated when we don't remember the name of the person celebrating one more year.)

We do like it very much when the whole song is pulled off well.  Many times that requires a solid leader to guide everyone else.  Maybe that can be you, once you find the key that suits you well.

P.S.  Some songs actually feature key changes.  Listen to some of Barry Manilow's tunes, and he'll go up a half step.  In "Can't Smile Without You" he does it more than once, and the band follows.

Comment: Oh, come on!  'Happy Birthday' is in F.  Just suck it up.

Answer (score 0):

In every situation when asked on the spot to transpose from my key I have from the point of view,  that the show must go on accommodated the musician.  I do this as I realize that not every working musician is completely competent with all keys for accompaniment.  But I would like to explain from a singer's point of view that up or down half is not a simple request, and never the best outcome for the singer - who's voice after all is usually in the case of a vocal piece the focal point of the performance. Usually the key chosen by the singer and her/his vocal coach was the optimum for the brilliance in the very individual sound of the singer's voice.  This developed over many hours/days/weeks of coaching and rehearsals of that piece.  I understand it happens, however I would appreciate accompanying musicians to also appreciate just what they are asking of the singer "on the spot".

Answer (score -1):

When the written key is intended for a different voice type - soprano vs. alto or (perhaps more likely in the context of popular music, male baritone vs. chest voice woman) a transposition of a 3rd or more is common.  But when the key's in the right ballpark, yes, even a semitone can really make a difference, both to how the song generally lies in the singer's range and to whether they can make a good job of the 'money note'.  Sometines the singer just copes.  But when they are featured, take the trouble to find their optimum key.

It's a great deal easier for an instrumentalist to transpose 'one up' or 'one down' than a larger interval.  The fact that the new key may be harmonically related is immaterial.

Answer (score -1):

I sing (somewhat) If I cant sing in the original key, I transpose a 4th or 5th. This maintains the same "feel" of the song. if I cant do it in a 4th or 5th, I just don't to the song